# New to Ruby on Rails, Local Host 3000 responding unpredictably

Tags: ruby

I had run into a few problems getting Ruby fully installed and working, so I could start building. I finished installing and tested my server at localhost:3000, and it came up fine. Then the next day when I tried to go back to it, it didn't connect and I could not figure out why.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. We have no way of knowing what the issue is if we don't have an error or a way to replicate it. What does `getting everything fully installed` mean? What are you trying to build? what frameworks? what webserver?

Comment: hey - sorry for the vagueness. Basically I installed Homebrew, RVM, Ruby and Rails, then I created a new application and connected it to a server. When I go to the localhost:3000 to verify the server connection, it connected originally, but when I tried to go back the next day, its no longer appearing. I'm using all of this to learn the basics using tutorials. But since I have no one with me, troubleshooting on the internet is my only option.

Comment: I originally used this tutorial. http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html and got to the end and everything worked.

Comment: I got it figured out, thanks for your help.

Comment: What problems did you run into? What errors are being shown?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no specific way for us to address this issue. You haven't mentioned any of what happened between the server working and malfunctioning? It could be as simple as the server not being started. Is the server currently running? If it is than you should have some sort of response when you try to hit localhost.3000.

Make sure your server is running with `rails s` and then let us know.

Perhaps you can try resetting your DB with a `rake db:reset` if that doesn't work.

Besides that, there really isn't anything we can do on this end without more information.

Comment: when I use rails s I get this message: Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /Users/DeepDream/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby

Comment: are you in the correct directory when you run `rails s`? what about running `rails c`?

Comment: hey - I got it figured out, I reinstalled rails and built a new directory and reconnected it to the server and everything is showing up now. Thanks for your help.